# Overload multiplication operator without use of templates

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

So I am trying to multiply an object by an constant like this,

```
    Vector3d v(2,4,6);
    Vector3d v1 = v0*2;
```

To overload the multiplication operator I have,

```
    class Vector3d
    {
         private:
              float x,y,z,a,b,c;
              string p;
         public:
              Vector3d(float a,float b,float c)
              {
                    x = a;
                    y = b;
                    z = c;
              }
              Vector operator*(const float& s) const
              {
                     return a * s;
                     return b * s;
                     return c * s;
              }
              void print(string s);
    };
```

I'm confused as to how it should be done as I have never implemented operator overloading and I'm guessing this is how it should be done. I have also still not learnt templates.

Comment: You may have made a mistake by having both `(x,y,z)` and `(a,b,c)`.  I'd look into that more closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator can be overloaded Something like the followimng

```
class Vector3d
{
     private:
          float x,y,z;
          string p;
     public:
          Vector3d(float a,float b,float c)
          {
                x = a;
                y = b;
                z = c;
          }
          Vector3d operator *( float s ) const
          {
                 return Vector3d( x * s, y * s, z * s );
          }
          void print(string s);
};
```

The return statement of the operator can be written also like

```
                 return { x * s, y * s, z * s };
```

Comment: Does operator + work the same way but instead addition , if I want to do this and also have another operator* function?,
     
            `Vector3d v2 = (v + v1) *v`

Comment: @user2948246 In fact these operators can be defined the same way only the parameter should be constant reference to Vector3d.